# How can I get UserId and UserName from the new ASP identity tables with MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my MVC4 application I had the following model:

```
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.webpages_Roles = new List<webpages_Roles>();
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I used a select with Entity Framework against this class / table to get a list of UserId's and UserNames.

Now I understand it's completely different with MVC5.

Can someone tell me how I can get the same information with MVC5? Is there a built in method that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate all of the users in the 1.0 RTM Identity bits via the EF specific IdentityDbContext.Users property.

In a future release(probably 1.1), we will be adding an IQueryable for TUser to the UserManager as well, so you don't have to drop down to the specific store to enumerate the users.